# Why do char arrays get lost when returning from a function in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, callstack, char-pointer

I know that, if we declare variables inside a function without allocating memory for them, they will be lost after the function finishes its job.

The following code prints:

```
(null)
5
```

```
char* getString() 
{ 
  char arr[] = "SomeText";
  return arr;  
}      

int getInt()
{
    int b = 5;
    return b;
}

int main() 
{ 
  printf("%s", getString());
  printf("\n");
  printf("%d", getInt());

  return 0; 
}
```

Both `arr` and `b` variables are created on the stack, so they both should be destroyed when the functions end. My question is, how come variable `b` doesn't get lost while variable `arr` is lost?

Comment: undefined behavior. Anything could happen.

Comment: The difference is the `getInt()` function returns a **value** and the `getString()` function returns a **pointer** (... to a memory area that has been disposed of). Try `int *getInts() { int x[2] = {-1, 42}; return x; }`

Comment: Local variables, which includes arrays, go out of scope and end their life-time when the function ends. Pointers to such variables (and you return a pointer to an arrays first element) will become invalid as soon as the function ends.

Comment: The local variable `b` **is** lost, but its *value* is returned by the function. It would be the same situation as with `arr` if you returned a *pointer* to `b`.

Comment: In C++ we solve this by returning a `std::string`. Pointers are building blocks for classes. `std::string` probably has a few pointers inside it. You don't care about that.

Comment: As fa r as I understand, the memory used by variable b can be used by any other thing. If that happens I will also lose variable b. @pmg Why does the value doesn't get lost?

Comment: Suppose passing "things" between functions is done with envelopes. When `getInt()` reaches the statement `return b;` it puts inside the envelope the value contained in the variable `b` at the time. The function `getString()` puts inside the envelope something like `0xdeadbeef` (the "decayed" `arr`).

Comment: Both functions return values. `getInt()` returns an integer value and `getString()` returns a `char*` value. Unfortunately the `char*` value returned is the address of an array that has gone out of scope and is no longer alive.

Comment: Look [here](https://ideone.com/QdoUWW). Now look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A unique and often confusing feature of C (and inherited by C++) is that an array when used in an expression is not treated as a collection of values, but (most of the time) as a pointer to its first element.<sup>†</sup> So, when you return an array from a function, you are returning the address of its first element.

> **Dereferencing the address of an object with automatic storage duration that is no longer in scope results in undefined behavior.**

When you return a value from a function, a copy of the value is returned to the caller.

Thus, when you return an integer, the caller receives a copy of that integer value.

If the value is a pointer, the copied value is a pointer. If the pointer is pointing to an invalid object, then if the receiver of the pointer tried to dereference the pointer value, it would result in undefined behavior.

---

<sup>**†**</sup> There are 3 exceptions: (1) As an operand to `&`; (2) As an operand to `sizeof`; and (3) A string literal used to initialize an array. In C++, there are other exceptions: (4) As an operand of `decltype`; (5) As the function argument to a reference parameter; (6) An object to initialize a reference variable; ... probably something else I am forgetting...

Answer (score 4):

Both `getInt` and `getString` return a value.

`getInt` returns an `int` value of 5. It remains 5 in the caller.

`getString` returns a `char *` value that points to `arr`. While the caller receives a pointer, the thing it points to, `arr`, no longer exists (in the C standard’s model of computation) when the function returns.

Thus, it is not the value being returned by the function that is the problem so much as its meaning. The number 5 retains its meaning. A pointer to a thing that ceases to exist does not retain its meaning.